# What is in the space between a nucleus of an atom and its electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atoms, subatomic

There is a common analogy about the structure of an atom, such as the nucleus is a fly in the centre of a sports stadium and the electrons are tiny tiny gnats circling the stadium (tip of the hat to 'The Greatest Show on Earth') but what is in the space between the 'fly' and circling 'gnats'?

Comment: You might enjoy pictures from here: http://vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/zoom-in-atom-or-unknown-physics-of-short-distances/

Comment: You might enjoy pictures from [**here**](http://vladimirkalitvianski.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/zoom-in-atom-or-unknown-physics-of-short-distances/).

Comment: The image is used only to convey an idea of the relative distances involved, not of the possible structure of what lies in an atom. A bit like using a [basketball and a tennisball to represent the Earth and the Moon.](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2011/02/24/how-far-away-is-the-moon/) But there are no giants holding up the Earth and the Moon, are there?

Comment: Or pictures from here: http://thisquantumworld.com/wp/?page_id=1462

Comment: I found this interesting post: http://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae222.cfm

Answer (score 13):

**Short answer:**
The space between the nucleus and the electron is not empty space, it is filled with an electron cloud. (You will understand this answer better if you read the long answer)

**Long answer:**
Firstly, physics is a description of what we can observe. Depending on the scale of which you are describing, physicists, over the years, have different mathematical descriptions describing at different scales.

When you ask about the space between the electron and the nucleus, confusion arises when trying to use a classical description to describe things on the atomic scale.

On the atomic scale, physicists have found that quantum mechanics describes things very well on that scale. And when we use quantum mechanics to describe particles, electrons, protons, neutrons, etc, they are no longer thought of as point like particles whizzing around like the description that you are confused about.

Particle locations in quantum mechanics are not at an exact position, they are described by a probability density function. The previous answers other people gave before me are links to pictures of a probability density function of Hydrogen at different energy levels in 3D space.

These probability density function's shapes are often known as "electron clouds". They show where it's likely to find the electron. The darker regions are places of higher probability of finding the electron and the lighter regions are lower probability of finding the electron.

An important thing to note is that the pictures show "white space". Its actually a smooth picture with the probability getting smaller and smaller so fast that those locations look "white". This means that the probability of finding the electron in those seemingly white spaces are extremely low.

Now what does it mean to "find and electron?" This is another question you will have to ask. Its not related to this question.

Comment: I don't think this is a concrete answer at all, because once you make a measurement, you definitely know where the electron is, and NOW we can ask the same intended question!  I'd say the answer is that the space is filled of virtual particles which make up the forces of interactions between the nucleus and electron.

Comment: I swear electrons are limited to only certain areas, at all. Because you can only have electrons at certain energy levels. So electrons are only "allowed" at specific distances from the nucleus?

Comment: These are orbitals that the wavefunction of the electron has dependent on its energy level, but its still a "smearing" over specific locations.

Comment: @Chris: once you make a measurement to see where the electron is, it is no longer in the atom. You just knocked it out. If it is in the atom, you can't know where it is. Further, this is an _in principle_ limitation, so you can't even assume that the electron is somewhere, and you just don't know where, because the calculus of ignorance is the calculus of probabilities, while the calculus of electron position is probability amplitudes. Probability amplitudes do not have an obvious ignorance interpretation, if it exists, it at best applies asymptotically, for large systems only.

Comment: Wrong: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/08/100804151355.htm  Fact is, saying the electron is smeared over the atom does not answer the question... there is vacuum of space between the nucleus and electron, which consist of virtual particles.

Comment: @Chris: Not wrong, please don't give references, they are useless. You can just say "what about Rydberg atoms?". It is indeed possible to approximately locate an electron in a highly excited _Rydberg_ atom without knocking it out, but this requires a highly excited state, and you can't locate the electron too precisely, or it is knocked out. The limitation on your location region is about the same size as the radius of the ground state, so it isn't really telling you where the electron is. It is impossible to say that the electron is somewhere, and this is known since 1925.

Comment: Right, but that does not imply that the space is filled with a 'cloud'... it is only a probability density.  The true answer is Anna V's post.

Comment: This answer is wrong... Electron cloud is found on certain quantized levels. There's always vacuum inside atom, unless it is compressed..

Comment: Chris Gerig, you've got to keep in mind the person who asked the question. Yeah, sure its filled with virtual particles. But the original person who asked the question is gonna get confused by this. Unless you now explain virtual particles too. Please do! So that it adds more depth to the answer.

Comment: Also, the person who's asking the question is mentally transitioning between the classical picture to the quantum one. It wouldn't help to blast a whole Tsunami of information in their face.

Comment: I would like to add that for S state orbitals, S being the zero angular momentum orbit, the solution goes right through the nucleus, so the electron probability certainly fills the inside spaces, which is how we can have capture nuclear reactions.

Comment: @Jonathan. a specific distance from the atom as each energy level Would be true if the 'orbitals' of electrons were perfectly circular, however because of movement (much like the sun and earths path) the paths are much more eliptical and distance changes very slightly because of this, so the concept of a cloud is thanks to non circular 'orbits' that describe a rough area (or cloud) in which an electron with that energy band could be found in (my description is very poor i agree, trying to explain such a concept is very difficult though!)

Comment: @RhysW No. You're trying to work from the Bohr picture which is horribly incomplete. You need to solve the 3d Schrödinger equation. The "orbitals" are *not* orbits and are instead [space filling three-dimensional functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Visualizing_the_hydrogen_electron_orbitals) (albeit with regions of zero probability called nodes). For high angular momentum states there are some of these functions which begin to approximate a fuzzy orbit, but those are the exception. The lowest lying states are spherically symmetric and strongest at the center fading outward.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe one should add to the analysis of @QEntanglement and the nice electron probability clouds in the illustrations in the other answers,  that also the space between the nucleus and the electrons is teaming with the exchange of virtual particles between the electrons and the nucleus, necessary to create the potential which determines the energy levels of the particles. These will mostly be virtual photons with loops and stuff.

Edit. This post was made duplicate  to a new question, but I think [my answer there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/695894/what-is-actually-in-between-the-gaps-of-nucleus-and-electrons/695903#695903) completes this answer of mine so I am adding the link.

Comment: Anna V. I agree with you. Perhaps Chris Gerig can do this for us. He seems very passionate about how my answer is wrong.